# How do I repeat a while loop statement in python?

Tags: python

I'm learning python and i'm making a 2 player dice-rolling game but i can't seem to allow the players to roll or play another round. This is the code that i've written. Id appreciate it if someone could help me correct the codes. Thankss!

```
import random
import time

player_a = input("Player1, please type your name:")
time.sleep(1)
player_b = input("Player2, please type your name:")
time.sleep(1)
print("Welcome to Dice Roller", player_a, "and", player_b)

score_a = 0
score_b = 0
roll_a = False
roll_b = False

while not (roll_a and roll_b):
    ans_a = input("Type roll to roll the dice:")
    if ans_a == "roll":
        roll_a = (random.randint(1, 6))
        time.sleep(1)
        print(player_a, "has rolled", roll_a)
    else:
        print("Please check you spelling")
        time.sleep(2)
    ans_b = input("Your turn to roll, type roll to roll the dice:")
    if ans_b == "roll":
       roll_b = (random.randint(1, 6))
        time.sleep(1)
        print(player_b, "has rolled", roll_b)
    if roll_a == roll_b:
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Tie")
    break 
    roll_a = False
    roll_b = False
    if roll_a > roll_b:
        score_a = roll_a - roll_b
        print(player_a, "has scored", score_a, "points")
    break 
    roll_a = False
    roll_b = False
    if roll_b > roll_a:
        score_b = roll_b - roll_a
        print(player_b, "has scored", score_b, "points")
    break 
    roll_a = False
    roll_b = False
```

Comment: There are 3 break statements inside your loop. The first one will exit the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to refactor your game to a function that requests the user(s) to type "roll" and returns the roll result, like below.

The main `while True` loop will never end (though you could make it something like `for round in range(5):` to play 5 rounds), and the `request_roll()` loop will be broken out of with the `return`.

```
import random
import time


def request_roll(name):
    while True:
        ans = input(f"{name}, type roll to roll the dice:").lower()
        if ans == "roll":
            roll = random.randint(1, 6)
            time.sleep(1)
            print(name, "has rolled", roll)
            return roll
        print("Please check your spelling")
        time.sleep(2)


player_a = input("Player1, please type your name:")
player_b = input("Player2, please type your name:")
print("Welcome to Dice Roller", player_a, "and", player_b)

while True:
    roll_a = request_roll(player_a)
    roll_b = request_roll(player_b)
    if roll_a > roll_b:
        score_a = roll_a - roll_b
        print(player_a, "has scored", score_a, "points")
    elif roll_b > roll_a:
        score_b = roll_b - roll_a
        print(player_b, "has scored", score_b, "points")
    else:
        print("It's a draw")
```

Comment: Nice answer. Maybe the `print("Please check your spelling")` should be in an `else` statement, it seems to be printed anyway and for best practice an error thrown to avoid an infinite loop ?

Comment: @cbo It doesn't need to be in an `else` block, since there's a `return` at the end of the `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

The `break` statements immediately quits the while loop so the code after the first `break` is never run. See the documentation here for more info: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_break_statement.htm

There are also several other issues with your code which have not shown up yet (because that section of code never gets run):

In the following section `roll_a` and `roll_b` get overwriten with `False`. This means the comparison in the if-statment will not work. You are also overwritting `score_a`, where I would assume you would want to add to it (use the `+=` operator instead of `=`).

```py
    roll_a = False
    roll_b = False
    if roll_a > roll_b:
        score_a = roll_a - roll_b
        print(player_a, "has scored", score_a, "points")
```

I would suggest something like the following (note I have not tested this!):

```py
play_another_round = True
while play_another_round:
    ans_a = input("Type roll to roll the dice:")
    if ans_a == "roll":
        roll_a = (random.randint(1, 6))
        time.sleep(1)
        print(player_a, "has rolled", roll_a)
    else:
        print("Please check you spelling")
        time.sleep(2)
    ans_b = input("Your turn to roll, type roll to roll the dice:")
    if ans_b == "roll":
       roll_b = (random.randint(1, 6))
        time.sleep(1)
        print(player_b, "has rolled", roll_b)

    if roll_a == roll_b:
        print("Tie") 
    elif roll_a > roll_b:
        score_a += roll_a - roll_b
        print(player_a, "has scored", score_a, "points")
    elif roll_b > roll_a:
        score_b += roll_b - roll_a
        print(player_b, "has scored", score_b, "points")

    continue_game_check = input("Do you want to play another round (Yes/No)?")
    play_another_round = continue_game_check == "Yes"

print("The game has ended")
print(player_a, "has scored", score_a, "points")
print(player_b, "has scored", score_b, "points")
```